# How to get original service's exception on Apache Ignite client?

Tags: kotlin, exception, ignite

Ley's say we have a service:

```
interface ExceptionService : Service {
    fun doSmth(flag: Boolean)
}
```

implementation:

```
class ExceptionServiceImpl : ExceptionService {
    override fun doSmth(flag: Boolean) {
        if (flag) {
            throw IOException("my IO exception")
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("my IllegalArgument exception")
        }
    }
}
```

We deploy it onto Ignite cluster:

```
Ignition.start(
    IgniteConfiguration()
        .setServiceConfiguration(
            ServiceConfiguration()
                .setService(ExceptionServiceImpl())
                .setName("service")
        )
)
```

And now we call it from client:

```
val client = Ignition.startClient(ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1"))
val service = client.services().serviceProxy("service", ExceptionService::class.java)
try {
    service.doSmth(true)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println(e.mesaage)
}
try {
    service.doSmth(false)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println(e.mesaage)
}
```

Console output will be:

```
Ignite failed to process request [1] my IO exception (server status code [1])
Ignite failed to process request [2] my IllegalArgument exception (server status code [1])
```

The problem is that the type of the caught exception is always `org.apache.ignite.client.ClientException`. The only thing that left from the original exceptions thrown on server is message, and even it is wrapped in other words. The cause is of type `org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientServerError`. Types are lost.
I want to handle on client side different types of exceptions thrown by service. Is there a way to do it? Maybe some Ignite configuration that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling [ThinClientConfiguration#sendServerExceptionStackTraceToClient](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ThinClientConfiguration.html#sendServerExceptionStackTraceToClient-boolean-)

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Eventhough it is not the perfect solution for my case (I still have to parse text for the root exception), it makes handling much easier.